# Image upload not working PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload

i'm trying to set up my site so that I can use a mobile device to upload an image. However whenever I attempt to upload the image it doesn't work and throws out two errors:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(UPLOADS/Image Attachment 27/03/16.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home3/hutch/public_html/stencylcollins/upload1.php on line 29
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpSZy8LW' to 'UPLOADS/Image Attachment 27/03/16.jpg' in /home3/hutch/public_html/stencylcollins/upload1.php on line 29

And after this I get my echo

> UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL: Your document has now been uploaded and is ready to send.

Anyone know what's going on here?

```
<?php
    //login 
    ob_clean();session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();  
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    //timezone 

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    $date = date('d/m/y', time());

    //upload 
    if(isset($_FILES['UploadFileField'])){
        $allowed = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
        $name = $_FILES["UploadFileField"]["name"];
        $tmp = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['tmp_name'];
        $type = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['type'];
        $newName = "Image Attachment ".$date.".jpg";
        $types = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
        $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(in_array($ext,$types)){
            move_uploaded_file($tmp, "UPLOADS/$newName");
            echo '<font color="#006600" size="3"><p align="center"><b>UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">Your document has now been uploaded and is ready to send.</b></p></font>';
        } 

        else {
            if(!$tmp){
                echo '<font color="#FF0000" size="3"><p align="center"><b>UPLOAD FAILED: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">No document has been selected.</b></p></font>';
            }

            else {
                echo '<font color="#FF0000" size="3"><p align="center"><b>UPLOAD FAILED: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">Uploaded document was an incorrect extension type, please use ".jpg", ".jpeg", or "png" only.</b></p></font>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hard to say for sure without knowing what the HTML form looks like. Plus, if on a * NIX server, `UPLOADS` isn't the same as `uploads`. Plus, I see a GET array, so make sure the form isn't using GET as opposed to POST including a valid enctype.

Comment: You've been given an "answer" below. I'll let you take it up with him. Whether or not it's a "solution", is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have slashes in a file name. The file name `Image Attachment 27/03/16.jpg` is totally invalid because you are actually referring to a file called `16.jpg` in the folder `03` which is itself in `Image Attachment 27`. None of these directories exist, hence your error.

Answer (score -2):

Filename with spaces??? i think this is a bad way.

```
 // $newName = "Image Attachment ".$date.".jpg"; ???
 $newName = "Image_Attachment_".$date.".jpg";

// you can check where you trying to upload a file
if(is_dir("UPLOADS/")) { echo "dir ok";} else { echo "dir not ok"; }
```

and in your code you dont need use `time()` into date function, because `date()` without second parameter returns current date :)

Comment: You can use it) But i think that it's bad practice